# Autofac parameter resolving from Model into Repository

Tags: autofac

How can I set parameter from Model: DatabaseName into MyRepository constructor during Autofac container registration?

Here is code sample:

```
public class ModelBase
{
    public string DatabaseName;
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : ModelBase
{

}

public class MyRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : ModelBase
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public MyRepository(string databaseName)
    {
        _connectionString = string.Format("DatabaseName='{0}';...", databaseName);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MyRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>));

        IContainer container = containerBuilder.Build();
        var someRepository = container.Resolve<IRepository<ModelBase>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean something like this: `var someRepository = container.Resolve<IRepository<ModelBase>>(new NamedParameter("someValueFromModel", "SomeValue"));` ? Or value must be picked from model somehow?

Comment: Value might be picked from Model. The value it`self if Name of database. Application has multiple databases... So, idea is to transfer database name from Model to Repository and than in repository generate connection string to DB depending on Value (DB Name) sent to Repository from Model.

Comment: Hm. Shouldn't `DatabaseName` be a static property in this case?

Comment: Potentially it also can be a static field as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you can try to extract value of `DatabaseName` from the generic argument of the repository using kinda code:

```
public class ModelBase
{
    public virtual string DatabaseName { get; } = "MyDataBase";
}

public class SubModelBase : ModelBase
{
    public override string DatabaseName { get; } = "AnotherDataBase";
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : ModelBase
{

}

public class MyRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : ModelBase
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public MyRepository(string databaseName)
    {
        _connectionString = string.Format("DatabaseName='{0}';...", databaseName);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MyRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).WithParameter((p, ctx) => true, (p, ctx) =>
        {
            var repType = p.Member.DeclaringType;
            var genericParamType = repType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            var prop = genericParamType.GetProperty("DatabaseName");
            var databaseName = prop.GetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(genericParamType));
            // or for static DatabaseName
            // var databaseName = prop.GetValue(null);
            return databaseName;
        });

        IContainer container = containerBuilder.Build();
        var someRepository = container.Resolve<IRepository<ModelBase>>();
        var anotherRepository = container.Resolve<IRepository<SubModelBase>>();
    }
}
```

Notice that `DatabaseName` must be determined for default `ModelBase` instance and type must have parameterless constructor. Or you can make `DatabaseName` static and make it assign it at compile time. In this case you can call `var databaseName = prop.GetValue(null);`.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Happy to help=)